# unable to navigate away from page via browser back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When these partials are loaded in the browser I am unable to navigate away from the page via the browser back button. The page stays the same but the url changes.

What could be causing this?

```
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'get'


# /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    render partial: "new", layout: false
  end

# /sessions/new
  def new
    render partial: "new", layout: false
  end
```

Here's my stack. This is from just clicking the signin link once.

```
Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#new as */*
Processing by SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)




Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)




Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-26 19:57:46 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Why do you have two definitions for your `new` method?

Comment: sorry, just updated the post. The first is a new user the other new session.

Comment: Really? I'm shocked no one has anything for this.

Comment: I had similar unwanted behavior when I was using Rails 3.2.12 and Turbolinks with 3rd party JS libraries. Do you happen to have that mixture ?

Comment: What is the match for '/signin'? You've given '/signup' but the log is for '/signin'. And do you really get those doubled lines and the three groups from the one request?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a before filter redirecting public access to sessions#new?  Have you defined /signin as a route?

Comment: Thanks. No before filter for redirecting to new session yet. There is a route for "/signin"

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but as I wrote in the comment while ago I had a customer that used Turbolinks on Rails 3.2.12 and a group of customized JS libraries. The Turbolinks was causing a lot of issues such as double submitting and one of them was a similar thing to what you have mentioned. I had 3 choices:

1- Take out Turbolinks (my temp solution, until I showed the team TL was causing it)

2- Change the JS lib dependencies

3- Update the Rails App to 4.x latest. (I did this finally, it wasn't too bad)

In case if I was wrong and your case and setup was not similar to mine, here is a good thread on Github that some guy tries to solve it and still seems to be open.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/256

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameters :

```
Processing SESSION::SESSION#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-04 13:50:03) [POST]
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XXXXX=", "param1"=>"1"}
```

Well in your log you will see what params you are sending if it is not sending what you want create params according to your columns or what you want to keep.

If you want create a back button you could try this:

```
link_to_function "Back", "history.back()"
```

Check your action form maybe you are sending other url

```
  <% form_tag :controller=>"sessions",:action=>"new" do %>
    <% @user.each do |user| %>
      <%= user.name %>
      <%= user.lastname %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```